# Ajax POST fails, but works in console

Tags: javascript, ajax

The ajax function below fails with an error message that just says "error" (so useful):

```
var form = formInfo;
var url = $(formInfo).attr("action");
var data = $(formInfo).serialize();
$.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: url,
            data: data,
            dataType: "text",
            **cache: false,**
            success: function (r) {
              //do stuff here
            }, error: function (r) {
              //do some logging stuff here
            }
 });
```

What's not making sense to me is that if I execute the same ajax call through the console, it posts successfully. Also, the post is successful if I put a breakpoint on the ajax call and debug through the backend code. Any ideas on what could be causing this error?

EDIT: it seems the issue was with caching, and adding the cache: false actually fixed the problem
EDIT 2: another problem was window.location was being called before ajax call was finished executing, so it was moved to a function called by success

Comment: wrap it in .ready function

Comment: When/How do you call it? My guess is you call it BEFORE the page is ready/loaded.

Comment: it's called from the ready function. page is loaded and other ajax calls are successfully made by the time this one is called

Answer (score 0):

Probably your form has not loaded yet when you make the request.

Wrap your code in `ready` function or just move your javascript to the end of the page.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //your code here
});
```